# How to change flag value in single query using sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm having one table, it's containing the column name like flag, that data's are looks like 'Y' or 'N'.

When I'll take a data from that table using "Select Flag from tablename" query means it shows only 'Y' or 'N'.

But what I need is, if it's 'Y' means 'Yes' or 'N' means 'No.

If we will use Stored procedure means we will do this concept easily using 'If' or 'Case' condition.

But I want to take that data using single query.

How can I do this?

Please help me friends...

Answer (score 0):

One way is with a case statement:

```
select (case when flag = 'Y' then 'Yes'
             when flag = 'N' then 'No'
             else 'Oops!'
        end) as FullFlag
from table t
```

You can also do this with a calculated column.  You could define the table and store the flag as a bit (which is as efficient as possible) and then use a computed column to retrieve another value:

```
create table . . . 
    FlagBit bit,
    Flag as (case when FlagBit = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end)
    . . .
```

Comment: Thank you so much...I tried without open and closing bracket..That's why it's shown error...Thank you so much Linoff

Comment: @AdisAksh: Note that if this answer has helped you out, you can [accept it formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?"), thus marking this question as solved. (If you like, you can delay your decision until later time to give someone else a chance to come up with a possibly better suggestion, but in any event please consider going over your *past* questions to see if you can accept some of the answers to them too.)